# More efficent and quickier way to generate numbers and insert into db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Hi all i have the following bit of code, which is used to generate telephone numbers and insert these into a table in a database. To generate the codes it looks in a table in the database to see which "F" digit numbers need generating for a range. So for example the Leeds range of "01132 21", needs numbers generating for 1,3,4 and 6. So the numbers generated would be like 01132211000-01132211999, 01132213000-01132213999, etc.

This is working as i wanted and as expected. However it is taking quite a long time (taken 12 hours to generate 120,000 records and i estimate we could have roughly a one million records generated. Just wondering if there is a quicker way to do what i want. I'm still a very "green" developer, so dont really know the best way to do things quite yet!

```
private TelephoneNumberManagementEntities context = new TelephoneNumberManagementEntities();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = context.TempNumberImports.ToList();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        string range = item.Range.ToString().Trim().Replace(" ","");

        if (item.C0 == "Y")
        {
            GenerateNumbers(range, 0, 999, item.ID);
        }
        if (item.C1 == "Y")
        {
            GenerateNumbers(range, 1000, 1999, item.ID);
        }
        if (item.C2 == "Y")
        {
            GenerateNumbers(range, 2000, 2999, item.ID);
        }
        if (item.C3 == "Y")
        {
            GenerateNumbers(range, 3000, 3999, item.ID);
        }
        if (item.C4 == "Y")
        {
            GenerateNumbers(range, 4000, 4999, item.ID);
        }
        if (item.C5 == "Y")
        {
            GenerateNumbers(range, 5000, 5999, item.ID);
        }
        if (item.C6 == "Y")
        {
            GenerateNumbers(range, 6000, 6999, item.ID);
        }
        if (item.C7 == "Y")
        {
            GenerateNumbers(range, 7000, 7999, item.ID);
        }
        if (item.C8 == "Y")
        {
            GenerateNumbers(range, 8000, 8999, item.ID);
        }
        if (item.C9 == "Y")
        {
            GenerateNumbers(range, 9000, 9999, item.ID);
        }
    }
    return View();
}

public void GenerateNumbers(string range, int startNo, int endNo, int rangeID)
{
    Number num = new Number();
    for (int i = startNo; i <= endNo; i++)
    {
        if (startNo == 0)
        {
            string tempNum = range + i.ToString("D4");
            var record = context.Numbers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Number1 == tempNum);
            if (record == null)
            {
                num.Number1 = tempNum;
                num.RangeID = rangeID;
                num.StatusID = 1;
                num.ImportDate = DateTime.Now;
                num.ImportSource = "Number Ranges 250811.xlsx";
                context.Numbers.Add(num);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string tempNum = range + i;
            var record = context.Numbers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Number1 == tempNum);
            if (record == null)
            {
                num.Number1 = tempNum;
                num.RangeID = rangeID;
                num.StatusID = 1;
                num.ImportDate = DateTime.Now;
                num.ImportSource = "Number Ranges 250811.xlsx";
                context.Numbers.Add(num);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: **USE STORED PROCEDURE**

Your current solution will produce thousands of database roundtrips because every single number will be inserted in separate database call.

You can also consider preparing data as batch and use `SqlBulkCopy`.